# K-Uniform Hypergraph Strong Coloring

Tags: graph-colouring, hypergraphs

I want to ask if strong coloring of a k-uniform hypergraph using only k colors is NP-Hard or NP-Complete? If you can add a reference this will be helpful.

Comment: Please don't cross-post, this question is perfectly fine for CS.SE.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/121160/755, https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/46397/5038.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).